# How to Fix layering on this progress bar?

Tags: html, css

I've built this progress bar but I need to put progress markers along the way, but I'm trying to put it in between the two existing layers.

I've tried some z-index work but I really don't understand it.

```
            #progress {
                background: grey;
                border-radius: 13px;
                height: 20px;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 3px;
            }

            .label-line {
                float: right;
                background: white;
                height:30px;
                width:2px;
                margin-left: 2px;
            }

            .bar-step {
                position:absolute;
                margin-top:-10px;
                font-size:12px;
            }

            #progress::after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                background: blue;
                width: 50%; /* THIS IS THE ACTUAL PROGRESS */
                height: 100%;
                border-radius: 9px;               
           }

<div id="progress">
                    <div class="bar-step" style="left: 30%">
                            <div class="label-line"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

The white line is in the very front of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `position: relative` and `z-index` to the progress bar pseudo element (`::after`) places it above the marker lines.

```css
#progress {
                background: grey;
                border-radius: 13px;
                height: 20px;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 3px;
            }

            .label-line {
                float: right;
                background: white;
                height:30px;
                width:2px;
                margin-left: 2px;
            }

            .bar-step {
                position:absolute;
                margin-top:-10px;
                font-size:12px;
            }

            #progress::after {
            
               position: relative; /* this is needed for z-index to work */
               z-index: 3;
               
                content: '';
                display: block;
                background: blue;
                width: 50%; /* THIS IS THE ACTUAL PROGRESS */
                height: 100%;
                border-radius: 9px;               
           }
```

```html
<div id="progress">
                    <div class="bar-step" style="left: 30%">
                            <div class="label-line"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```